# How to use map function in my code below instead of collect function?

Tags: java, kafka-producer-api

Kafka producer tries to send bulk message (10k) at a time but after transferring 3k it's start throwing error. I have used collect function in below code that might be a problem so I want to replace that with map.

```java
//Memberjson is JavaRDD<String>

for (String outputMbrJson : memberjson.collect()) {

    try {

        Producer kafkaProducer = new Producer(configFile);

        kafkaProducer.runProducer(Arrays.asList(outputMbrJson).iterator());
        } 
        catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
---------------------------------------
//runProducer method 

public Iterator<String> runProducer(Iterator<String> jsons) throws Exception {

        final Producer<Long, String> producer = createProducer();

        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            while (jsons.hasNext()) {
                String jsonobj = jsons.next();

                ret.add(EMPTY_STRING);
                try {
                    ProducerRecord<Long, String> record = new ProducerRecord<Long, String>(conf.getProperty("producer.topic"), jsonobj.toString());

                    producer.send(record);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            producer.flush();
            producer.close();
        }
        return ret.iterator();
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are using Collecting to list?

Comment: for (String outputMbrJson : memberjson.collect()) {
 first line of the code