# How many messages can we send to kafka topic in one go using kafka producer

Tags: kafka-producer-api

I am trying to send bulk message of 10k records to kafka topic. Producer application is working fine for 3k records but for bulk load it is throwing error as `Failed to construct kafka producer`

```
BOOTSTRAP_SERVER: xyz
TOPIC: xyz_topic
ACK: all
BATCH_SIZE: 16384
BUFFER_MEMORY: 33554432
BLOCK_ON_BUFFER_FULL: true
MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 5048576
MAX_MESSAGE_BYTE: 5000000
MESSAGE_MAX_BYTE: 5000000
CLIENT_ID: kafka_producer
LINGER_MS: 3
RETRIES: 3
RETRY_BACKOFF_MS: 100
```

Please provide any configuration that I am missing.

Comment: Can you add sample code of your producer along with the exact error that you see on the console/log?

Comment: please find another question related to same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744282/how-to-use-map-function-in-my-code-below-instead-of-collect-function?noredirect=1#comment100047404_56744282